# How to design a more flexible structure for my service layer

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

Talking about *Interface Segregation Principle* I was evaluating the design of an interface that I often use in my service layer:

```
public interface ICrudService<D>
{
    IList<D> GetAll();

    bool Exists(int id);

    D GetById(int id);

    D NewInstance();

    D Create(D dto);

    D Update(D dto);

    void Delete(int id);
}
```

I usually use an abstract implementation of this interface and inherit my concrete services from the abstract class.

But obviously I don't always need all of these methods in my service classes, so I'd like to make this structure more flexible.

An option could be to split my interface (and my abstract class) this way:

```
public interface IGetAllService<D>
{
    IList<D> GetAll();
}

public interface IExistsService<D>
{
    bool Exists(int id);
}

// etc.
```

And then just implement desired methods in my concrete class:

```
public class ConcreteService : IGetAllService<ConcreteEntity>, IExistsService<ConcreteEntity>
{
    // implemented methods
}
```

But is it good design?

Is there a better way to make my application structure more flexible and reusable?

Comment: Better on [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) i think. My only advice is not to limit yourself to integer keys - use another generic param to indicate the key type: `IGetByIdService<TEntity,TKey>{..}`

Comment: @Jamiec : code review is for existing, complete, working code. Design questions are more at home at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ imho.

Comment: @cosmo0 fair enough, im not that active on either TBH. This is more-or-less working code.

Comment: What are you using the interface for? Could you simply not have an interface and rely on convention?

Comment: @usr actually the point is the abstract class that I'm using to avoid code repetition. I'd like to maintain a general implementation for every method, but I don't always need all of them...

Comment: I see. There's an abstract class involved? Don't misuse inheritance for code reuse. Inheritance is for creating substitutability. Create yourself a few helper methods. That way you can create just the methods you want to expose.

Comment: @usr thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are deriving from an abstract class to inherit default implementations. Don't misuse inheritance for code reuse. Inheritance is for creating substitutability. Create yourself a few helper methods. That way you can create just the methods you want to expose.